# Passwordless continuous deployment from CircleCI to AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, circleci

The [CircleCI appengine documentation](https://circleci.com/docs/deploy-google-app-engine) suggests using a password to do deployment. How can I use the oauth2 flow instead of using passwords? I don't want to share my Google password.

Do I generate a `~/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java` file, from token data stored as environment variables in CircleCI? Is there a simpler way?

Comment: There is also the app passwords that you can generate when you have 2 steps verification enabled I believe.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue this way:

```
deployment:
  appengine:
    branch: master
    commands:
      - erb .appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java.json > ~/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java # requires ENV in circle ci
      - mvn -DskipTests=true appengine:update # tests have already been run
```

.appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java.json:

```
{
    "credentials": {
        "ubuntu": {
            "access_token": "<%= ENV["GOOGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN"] %>",
            "expiration_time_millis": 1431552739090,
            "refresh_token": "<%= ENV["GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN"] %>"
        }
    }
}
```

Then in CircleCI, configure the ENV variables for the two tokens. I got the tokens by locally running `mvn appengine:update` and going through the oAuth2 dance. Note: You may have to remove your existing `~/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java` file first.

Comment: For non-Java languages, you can use `appcfg.py update . --oauth2_refresh_token='<token>'`.  That token can be found in `~/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens` after going through the interactive oauth2 flow.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the AppEngine SDK docs, it sounds like that would be a good approach.  There is not a built-in way to do that on CircleCI.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any user-related credential, you can leverage service accounts, like mentioned in this blog post:
[Continuous Deployment with Google App Engine and CircleCI](http://blog.glop.org/2015/10/08/continuous-deployement-with-google-app-engine-and-circleci.html)

Comment: Did you try? Because it's not language specific.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way on the latest GAE SDK 1.9.34 for Java.

Assuming you have a Base64 encoded ENV Variable with your JSON key for a service account you've created on the GCloud project:

```
dependencies:
  pre:
    - echo $GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET | base64 --decode > ${HOME}/client-secret.json
```

And then in the deployment section:

```
- $HOME/appengine-java-sdk-$APP_ENGINE_VERSION/bin/appcfg.sh -A $GCLOUD_PROJECT -M $GCLOUD_MODULE -V $BUILD_VERSION --service_account_json_key_file=$HOME/client-secret.json update $WAR_FOLDER
```

The **--service_account_json_key_file** doesn't seem to appear as an option when you use **appcfg.sh help** but it is there, and does work.